# Exposing fields from an opaque C struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with an existing C library (that I can't modify) where some structures have opaque fields that must be accessed through specific setters and getters, like in the following crude example (imagining `x` is private, even though it's written in C).

```
struct CObject {
    int x;
};

void setCObjectX(CObject* o, int x) {
    o->x = x;
}

int getCObjectX(CObject* o) {
    return o->x;
}
```

I am writing classes that privately own these types of structures, kind of like wrappers, albeit more complex. I want to expose the relevant fields in a convenient way. At first, I was simply writing setters and getters wherever necessary. However, I thought of something else, and I wanted to know if there are any downsides to the method. It uses function pointers (`std::function`) to store the C setter-getter pairs and present them as if directly accessing a field instead of functions.

Here is the generic class I wrote to help define such "fake" fields:

```
template<typename T>
struct IndirectField {
    void operator=(const T& value) {
        setter(value);
    }
    auto operator()() const -> T {
        return *this;
    }
    operator T() const {
        return getter();
    }

    std::function<void(const T&)> setter;
    std::function<T()> getter;
};
```

It is used by defining an instance in the C++ class and setting up `setter` and `getter` with the corresponding C functions:

```
IndirectField<int> x;
// ...
x.setter = [=](int x) {
    setCObjectX(innerObject.get(), x);
};
x.getter = [=]() {
    return getCObjectX(innerObject.get());
};
```

[Here is a complete, working code for testing.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70ece2b40b1285a9)

Are there any disadvantages to using this method? Could it lead to eventual dangerous behaviors or something?

Comment: Can you explain what you aimed to gain vs a proper "normal" interface? On first sight it does not look like it would improve readability or debuggability too much.

Comment: Why have "fake fields" when you could just have... public fields?

Comment: @RnR I mostly wanted to remove typical setter-getter pairs, which I'm guessing you are refering to as proper "normal" interfaces. You say it wouldn't improve readability or debuggability, but would you say it impairs it? If not, then it would surely be a matter of style, and I'm reluctant to use setters and getters.

Comment: `std::function` is not a pointer and incurs huge overhead costs.

Comment: @PasserBy Because they come from existing structs and have to be accessed through the existing interface.

Comment: I still don't understand. You are wrapping a struct and exposing it's fields without restrictions. Why do you not just leave it be?

Comment: @PasserBy The title mentions "opaque C struct", meaning that the actual members are not declared in a public header file, only functions to get and set them.

Comment: @ascheplet ahhhhh..... I have reading problems :P

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for clarifying that for me. I edited, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @Nelfeal I do think it impairs it - say you want to break when someone sets or gets one of these fields - how do you do this with a "smart" indirect field? It also impacts readability - no one will expect the kinds of things that happen here to happen when they read struct.x = 5 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem I see with your solution is that `std::function` objects take space inside each instance of `IndirectField` inside `CPPObject`, even when `CObject` type is the same.

You can fix this problem by making function pointers into template parameters:

```
template<typename T,typename R,void setter(R*,T),T getter(R*)>
struct IndirectField {
    IndirectField(R *obj) : obj(obj) {
    }
    void operator=(const T& value) {
        setter(obj, value);
    }
    auto operator()() const -> T {
        return *this;
    }
    operator T() const {
        return getter(obj);
    }
private:
    R *obj;
};
```

Here is how to use this implementation:

```
class CPPObject {
    std::unique_ptr<CObject,decltype(&freeCObject)> obj;
public:
    CPPObject()
    :   obj(createCObject(), freeCObject)
    ,   x(obj.get())
    ,   y(obj.get()) {
    }
    IndirectField<int,CObject,setCObjectX,getCObjectX> x;
    IndirectField<double,CObject,setCObjectY,getCObjectY> y;
};
```

This approach trades two `std::function` objects for one `CObject*` pointer per `IndirectField`. Unfortunately, storing this pointer is required, because you cannot get it from the context inside the template.

[Your modified demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0dd839f039765e3)

Comment: At first I loled at the readability and usability of this, but then I thought that if one not-completely-black-magic line can efficiently wrap such object, it makes much sense. Many of such definitions are easily "bundable". **I guess I am trying to say that this is nicer than it looks**.

Comment: If I have another kind of getter with signatures like `int getter(R*, T*)`, modifying the T object through a pointer and returning an indication of success or failure, should I just create another class (or specialize `IndirectField`)? The main advantage I had by using `std::function` is that I could set them to lambdas, where I could treat different cases. I might be demanding too much though.

Comment: @Nelfeal right, lambdas give you more flexibility at the price of using more memory. I would make a separate template for each signature group, because that would save memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any disadvantages to using this method?

There's a few things to highlight in your code:

1. Your getters & setters, being not part of the class, break encapsulation. (Do you really want to tie yourself permanently to this library?)
2. Your example shows a massive amount of copying being done; which will be slower than it needs to be.  (`auto operator()()`, `operator T()` to name but 2).
3. It's taking up more memory than you need to and adds more compexity than just passing around a Cobject.  If you don't want things to know that it's a CObject, then create an abstract class and pass that abstract class around (see below for example).

> Could it lead to eventual dangerous behaviors or something?

The breaking of encapsulation will result in x changing from any number of routes; and force other things to know about how it's stored in the object.  Which is bad.

The creation of `IndirectField` Means that every object will have to have getters and setters in this way; which is going to be a maintenance nightmare.

Really I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
struct xProvider {
    virtual int getX() const = 0;
    virtual void setX() = 0;
};
struct MyCObject : xProvider {
private:
    CObject obj;
public:
    int getX() const override {return obj.x;}
    CObject& getRawObj() {return obj;}
    // etc ...
}
```

And then you just pass a reference / pointer to an xProvider around.
This will remove the dependence on this external C library; allowing you to replace it with your own test struct or a whole new library if you see fit; without having to re-write all your code using it

Comment: "I am working with a C library...": the OP cannot change the definition or existing interface functions of `CObject`.

Comment: @aschepler updated example.  (like PasserBy, I also have reading problems; but it doesn't change the answer much)

Comment: The classes I'm writing _privately own_ the existing structures. They are not going to change from other routes. Also, I'm already tied to the library, so this is not a problem. Moreover, I am not looking for polymorphism. I don't get what `xProvider` would accomplish here. I could just write setters and getters in the owner class (`MyCObject` in your example).

Comment: @Nelfeal it's providing the functionality you're looking for - while giving the compiler a chance to optimise things away.

Answer (score 0):

in a `struct` by default (as you post) all the fields are `public`, so they are accessible by client software.  I you want to make them accessible to derived classes (you don't need to reimplement anything if you know the field contract and want to access it in a well defined way) they are made `protected`.  And if you want them to be accessed by nobody, then mark them as `private`.

If the author of such a software doesn't want the fields to be touched by you, he will mark them as `private`, and then you'll have nothing to do, but to adapt to this behaviour.  Failing to do will give you bad consequences.

Suppose you make a field that is modified with a `set_myField()` method, that calls a list of listeners anytime you make a change.  If you bypass the method accessing function, all the listeners (many of them of unknown origin) will be bypassed and won't be notified of the field change.  This is quite common in object programming, so you must obey the rules the authors impose to you.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the problem. At the risk of repeating myself, the library itself is in C and there is no `private` in C. Moreover, I am not bypassing the library setters and getters; quite the contrary.

Comment: You don't seem to explain yourself, you talk about C, say that there's no `private` in C (I know that) but then use a class (in C++) derived from that `struct`. If you make a mistake (which is assumed, as you come to StackOverflow) we cannot guess if it resides in the tagging, the language or the example you put (which is far from the complete, verifiable and testable example required)  Please, proceed and tell us why you use C++ code if your example is plain C.

Comment: You need to carefully read the question over again. A question on StackOverflow is not necessarily about a "mistake"; assuming that is just wrong. Moreover, the example I show is clearly written in C++. Plus, I did provide a complete example, although I put it behind a link because it is not essential to the question. Once again, assuming a complete example is a required part of any question is just wrong. Finally, I don't see where you got that I derived my class from the C struct: there is no inheritance anywhere in my code.